# Can anyone explain a problem in transformer with dot convention?

Tags: transformer

Can anyone explain a problem in transformer with dots?

Comment: Yes, I am sure someone can. But to get a meaningful answer you must ask a meaningful question.

Comment: You will need to add more detail if you want assistance.

Comment: If you're just after an explanation of the dots and don't have a specific problem in mind it's covered here: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/66708/dots-in-a-transformer-symbol

Comment: A good question usually needs a bit more background info. I was about to edit your question because I thought you asked about what the dots mean, but that's covered already, as @PeterJ has pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a problem, it's a convention. The dots show the phase relationship of the voltages. The AC swings positive and negative so coils could be in phase or out of phase. The dot ends are all in phase.