# Meaning of these inductor dot symbols

Tags: transformer, inductor, sepic

For the following circuit from the NCV5171 [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncv5171-d.pdf):

[image]

What is the meaning of a solid dot on one inductor and an open dot on the other?

Comment: Doe this [What do phase dots on an inductor mean?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/what-do-phase-dots-on-an-inductor-mean) answer your question?

Comment: I understand the concept of mutual inductance and transformers, but I usually only see solid dots on the inductors. I'm not familiar with dots that are patterned differently (one is solid, the other is open).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is intentional, and doesn't mean anything.

The dots show the phase of the winding because in the SEPIC they are coupled as in a 1:1 transformer. The open versus the solid dot is not meaningful.